# QPROP vs RPROP in neural networks

Tags: neural-network

Which one neural network is faster during study resilent propogation or quick propogation. If to judge by name quick is faster, but in my expeirments it wasn't always. To be honest percentage was 50/50. I'd like to know am I alone in my conclusion, or there is somebody else who achieved similar results?

Comment: RProp was suggested as an improvement over Quickprop. See this [link](http://deeplearning.cs.cmu.edu/pdfs/Rprop.pdf)